# GL_INVALID_OPERATION after calling glBindVertexArray(VAO)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, opengl

Everything works up until this step where I get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error (code 1282).  I've confirmed that every opengl function before glBindVertexArray(VAO) return no error codes.  I'm also sure that my context is okay because I'm able to draw a simple clearcolor to the screen just fine.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/glcorearb.h>
#include <GL/wglext.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_procedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void *get_proc(const char *);

HMODULE gl_module;
bool quit = false;

PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGARBPROC wglGetExtensionsStringARB;
PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC wglChoosePixelFormatARB;
PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB;
PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC glGetString;
PFNGLCLEARCOLORPROC glClearColor;
PFNGLCLEARPROC glClear;
PFNGLVIEWPORTPROC glViewport;
PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC glGenBuffers;
PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC glBindBuffer;
PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC glBufferData;
PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC glCreateShader;
PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC glShaderSource;
PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC glCompileShader;
PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC glGetShaderiv;
PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC glGetShaderInfoLog;
PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC glCreateProgram;
PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC glAttachShader;
PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC glLinkProgram;
PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC glUseProgram;
PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC glDeleteShader;
PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC glVertexAttribPointer;
PFNGLENABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC glEnableVertexAttribArray;
PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSPROC glGenVertexArrays;
PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYPROC glBindVertexArray;
PFNGLDRAWARRAYSPROC glDrawArrays;
PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC glGetProgramiv;
PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC glGetShaderInfoLog;
PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC glGetProgramInfoLog;
PFNGLGETERRORPROC glGetError;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instance_handle, HINSTANCE prev_instance_handle, PSTR cmd_line, int cmd_show)
{

    // Create Window and register it
    WNDCLASS window_class;

    ZeroMemory(&window_class, sizeof(window_class));

    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_OWNDC;
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_procedure;
    window_class.hInstance = instance_handle;
    window_class.lpszClassName = TEXT("OPENGL_WINDOW");

    RegisterClass(&window_class);
    ///////////////////////////////////

    /* CREATE DUMMY WINDOW TO MAKE DC */
    HWND window_handle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                        TEXT("OPENGL_WINDOW"),
                                        TEXT("OPENGL_WINDOW"),
                                        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                        0, 0,
                                        0, 0,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL,
                                        instance_handle,
                                        NULL);

    HDC dc = GetDC(window_handle);

    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR descriptor;

    ZeroMemory(&descriptor, sizeof(descriptor));

    descriptor.nSize = sizeof(descriptor);
    descriptor.nVersion = 1;
    descriptor.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_DRAW_TO_BITMAP | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_GENERIC_ACCELERATED | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SWAP_LAYER_BUFFERS;
    descriptor.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    descriptor.cColorBits = 32;
    descriptor.cRedBits = 8;
    descriptor.cGreenBits = 8;
    descriptor.cBlueBits = 8;
    descriptor.cAlphaBits = 8;
    descriptor.cDepthBits = 32;
    descriptor.cStencilBits = 8;

    int pixel_format = ChoosePixelFormat(dc, &descriptor);
    SetPixelFormat(dc, pixel_format, &descriptor);

    HGLRC rc = wglCreateContext(dc);
    wglMakeCurrent(dc, rc);

    gl_module = LoadLibrary(TEXT("opengl32.dll"));

    wglGetExtensionsStringARB = (PFNWGLGETEXTENSIONSSTRINGARBPROC)get_proc("wglGetExtensionsStringARB");
    wglChoosePixelFormatARB = (PFNWGLCHOOSEPIXELFORMATARBPROC)get_proc("wglChoosePixelFormatARB");
    wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)get_proc("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
    glGetString = (PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC)get_proc("glGetString");    //
    glClearColor = (PFNGLCLEARCOLORPROC)get_proc("glClearColor"); //
    glClear = (PFNGLCLEARPROC)get_proc("glClear");                //
    glViewport = (PFNGLVIEWPORTPROC)get_proc("glViewport");       //
    glGenBuffers = (PFNGLGENBUFFERSPROC)get_proc("glGenBuffers");
    glBindBuffer = (PFNGLBINDBUFFERPROC)get_proc("glBindBuffer");
    glBufferData = (PFNGLBUFFERDATAPROC)get_proc("glBufferData");
    glCreateShader = (PFNGLCREATESHADERPROC)get_proc("glCreateShader");
    glShaderSource = (PFNGLSHADERSOURCEPROC)get_proc("glShaderSource");
    glCompileShader = (PFNGLCOMPILESHADERPROC)get_proc("glCompileShader");
    glGetShaderiv = (PFNGLGETSHADERIVPROC)get_proc("glGetShaderiv");
    glGetShaderInfoLog = (PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC)get_proc("glGetShaderInfoLog");
    glCreateProgram = (PFNGLCREATEPROGRAMPROC)get_proc("glCreateProgram");
    glAttachShader = (PFNGLATTACHSHADERPROC)get_proc("glAttachShader");
    glLinkProgram = (PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC)get_proc("glLinkProgram");
    glVertexAttribPointer = (PFNGLVERTEXATTRIBPOINTERPROC)get_proc("glVertexAttribPointer");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray = (PFNGLENABLEVERTEXATTRIBARRAYPROC)get_proc("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    glGenVertexArrays = (PFNGLGENVERTEXARRAYSPROC)get_proc("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    glBindVertexArray = (PFNGLBINDVERTEXARRAYPROC)get_proc("glBindVertexArray");
    glDrawArrays = (PFNGLDRAWARRAYSPROC)get_proc("glDrawArrays");
    glGetProgramiv = (PFNGLGETPROGRAMIVPROC)get_proc("glGetProgramiv");
    glGetShaderInfoLog = (PFNGLGETSHADERINFOLOGPROC)get_proc("glGetShaderInfoLog");
    glGetProgramInfoLog = (PFNGLGETPROGRAMINFOLOGPROC)get_proc(("glGetProgramInfoLog"));
    glUseProgram = (PFNGLUSEPROGRAMPROC)get_proc("glUseProgram");
    glDeleteShader = (PFNGLDELETESHADERPROC)get_proc(("glDeleteShader"));
    glGetError = (PFNGLGETERRORPROC)get_proc("glGetError");

    FreeLibrary(gl_module);

    int pixel_format_arb = 0;
    UINT pixel_formats_found = 0;

    int pixel_attributes[] = {
        WGL_SUPPORT_OPENGL_ARB, 1,
        WGL_DRAW_TO_WINDOW_ARB, 1,
        WGL_DRAW_TO_BITMAP_ARB, 1,
        WGL_DOUBLE_BUFFER_ARB, 1,
        WGL_SWAP_LAYER_BUFFERS_ARB, 1,
        WGL_COLOR_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_RED_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_GREEN_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_BLUE_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_ALPHA_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_DEPTH_BITS_ARB, 32,
        WGL_STENCIL_BITS_ARB, 8,
        WGL_ACCELERATION_ARB, WGL_FULL_ACCELERATION_ARB,
        WGL_PIXEL_TYPE_ARB, WGL_TYPE_RGBA_ARB,
        0};

    BOOL result = wglChoosePixelFormatARB(dc, pixel_attributes, NULL, 1, &pixel_format_arb, &pixel_formats_found);

    /* RECREATE WINDOW */
    wglMakeCurrent(dc, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(rc);
    ReleaseDC(window_handle, dc);
    DestroyWindow(window_handle);

    window_handle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                   TEXT("OPENGL_WINDOW"),
                                   TEXT("OPENGL_WINDOW"),
                                   WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                                   ((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - 800) / 2), ((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - 600) / 2),
                                   800, 600,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL,
                                   instance_handle,
                                   NULL);

    dc = GetDC(window_handle);

    SetPixelFormat(dc, pixel_format, &descriptor);

    ShowWindow(window_handle, SW_SHOW);
    /* NEW CONTEXT */
    GLint context_attributes[] = {
        WGL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, 3,
        WGL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB, WGL_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
        0};

    rc = wglCreateContextAttribsARB(dc, 0, context_attributes);
    wglMakeCurrent(dc, rc);

    const char *vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                     "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
                                     "void main()\n"
                                     "{\n"
                                     "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
                                     "}\0";
    const char *fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
                                       "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
                                       "void main()\n"
                                       "{\n"
                                       "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
                                       "}\n\0";

    unsigned int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // fragment shader
    unsigned int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    // link shaders
    unsigned int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    float vertices[] = {
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, // left
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  // right
        0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f    // top
    };

    GLuint VBO, VAO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    printf("%d\n", VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    GLenum error = glGetError();
    printf("%d", error);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // note that this is allowed, the call to glVertexAttribPointer registered VBO as the vertex attribute's bound vertex buffer object so afterwards we can safely unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other
    // VAOs requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    /* EVENT PUMP */
    MSG msg;

    while (true)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;

            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO); // seeing as we only have a single VAO there's no need to bind it every time, but we'll do so to keep things a bit more organized
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        SwapBuffers(dc);
    }

    return 0;
}

// Procedure that processes window events
LRESULT CALLBACK window_procedure(HWND window_handle, UINT message, WPARAM param_w, LPARAM param_l)
{
    return DefWindowProc(window_handle, message, param_w, param_l);
}

/* A procedure for getting OpenGL functions and OpenGL or WGL extensions.
   When looking for OpenGL 1.2 and above, or extensions, it uses wglGetProcAddress,
   otherwise it falls back to GetProcAddress. */
void *get_proc(const char *proc_name)
{
    void *proc = (void *)wglGetProcAddress(proc_name);

    if (!proc)
    {
        proc = (void *)GetProcAddress(gl_module, proc_name);
    }

    return proc;
}
```

Comment: Why are you directly loading OpenGL functions? Does the same code work with a loading library like GLEW?

Comment: Why are you loading GL functions before you've made your final Core context current?

Comment: ["Indeed, the function pointers `wglGetProcAddress()` returns are themselves context-specific. The Windows documentation for this function states that the functions returned *may* work with another context, depending on the vendor of that context and that context's pixel format. "](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions#Windows)

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget No particular reason.  I'm trying to get as close to the metal here as possible to learn how windows works with opengl

Comment: @genpfault Can you explain your comment?  I was under the assumption that I needed to create a dummy context to be able to load the wgl extensions and then I could create a real window using them.

Comment: @genpfault I tried loading the gl functions after setting the render context made with wglCreateContextAttribsARB to current.  There was no change.

Comment: Remove all the other OpenGL calls, just do `glGenVertexArrays` to create the VAO, then `glBindVertexArray` to bind the VAO. Does it still return an error?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget Yes, I still get the error.  Maybe the descriptor isn't good and I'm not getting a good pixel format?

Comment: Ah! That may be the case. What does `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` return?

Comment: @newQOpenGLWidget It returns 51. That is 3.3.0 NVIDIA 516.59

Comment: By the way, does `glGenVertexArrays` return an error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247490/discussion-between-john-ingles-and-new-qopenglwidget).